Chat Template Error when using HuggingFace and LangGraph
I'm following the LangGraph and LangChain tutorial on making a chatbot, and got a successful output on the first step. After binding tools and finishing the second step, this error occurs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[CENSORED]\beegmodel.py", line 111, in <module>
    stream_graph_updates('Who is Elon Musk?')
  File "[CENSORED]\beegmodel.py", line 106, in stream_graph_updates
    for event in graph.stream({"messages": [("user", user_input)]}):
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\__init__.py", line 1315, in stream
    for _ in runner.tick(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\runner.py", line 56, in tick
    run_with_retry(t, retry_policy)
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langgraph\pregel\retry.py", line 29, in run_with_retry
    task.proc.invoke(task.input, config)
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langgraph\utils\runnable.py", line 410, in invoke
    input = context.run(step.invoke, input, config, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langgraph\utils\runnable.py", line 184, in invoke
    ret = context.run(self.func, input, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\beegmodel.py", line 87, in chatbot
    return {"messages": [llm_with_tools.invoke(state["messages"])]}
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 5354, in invoke
    return self.bound.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 286, in invoke
    self.generate_prompt(
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 786, in generate_prompt
    return self.generate(prompt_messages, stop=stop, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 643, in generate
    raise e
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 633, in generate
    self._generate_with_cache(
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 851, in _generate_with_cache
    result = self._generate(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langchain_huggingface\chat_models\huggingface.py", line 373, in _generate
    llm_input = self._to_chat_prompt(messages)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\langchain_huggingface\chat_models\huggingface.py", line 410, in _to_chat_prompt
    return self.tokenizer.apply_chat_template(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1801, in apply_chat_template
    chat_template = self.get_chat_template(chat_template, tools)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[CENSORED]\Lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1962, in get_chat_template
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot use chat template functions because tokenizer.chat_template is not set and no template argument was passed! For information about writing templates and setting the tokenizer.chat_template attribute, please see the documentation at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/chat_templating

However the model's tokenizer_config.json does have a chat_template field. Here is my script (albeit not formatted well, but again this is just to get the basics down):
import torch
from transformers import (
    AutoConfig, MistralForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline
)
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download
from accelerate import (
    init_empty_weights,
    load_checkpoint_and_dispatch,
    infer_auto_device_map
)
from pprint import pprint
from collections import Counter
import time

# https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/31544#issuecomment-2188510876

torch.cuda.empty_cache()
torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32 = True
torch.backends.cudnn.allow_tf32 = True

checkpoint = 'mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2'
weights_location = snapshot_download(
    repo_id=checkpoint,
    allow_patterns=[
        '*.safetensors',
        '*.json'
    ],
    ignore_patterns=[
        '*pytorch*',
        'consolidated.safetensors'
    ]
)

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

with init_empty_weights():
    model = MistralForCausalLM._from_config(config, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

# Much better than 'device_map="auto"'
device_map = infer_auto_device_map(model, dtype=torch.bfloat16)
model = load_checkpoint_and_dispatch(
    model, checkpoint=weights_location, device_map=device_map
)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
pipe = pipeline(
    'text-generation',
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    max_new_tokens=512,
    do_sample=False,
    repetition_penalty=1.03,
)

from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFacePipeline, ChatHuggingFace

llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)

from langchain_community.tools import WikipediaQueryRun, BaseTool, Tool
from langchain_community.utilities import WikipediaAPIWrapper

from typing import Annotated

from langchain_anthropic import ChatAnthropic
from langchain_community.tools.tavily_search import TavilySearchResults
from langchain_core.messages import BaseMessage
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

from langgraph.graph import StateGraph
from langgraph.graph.message import add_messages
from langgraph.prebuilt import ToolNode, tools_condition


class State(TypedDict):
    messages: Annotated[list, add_messages]


graph_builder = StateGraph(State)


wikipedia_tool = WikipediaQueryRun(api_wrapper=WikipediaAPIWrapper(top_k_results=1, doc_content_chars_max=2500))
tools = [wikipedia_tool]
llm = ChatHuggingFace(llm=llm, verbose=True)
llm_with_tools = llm.bind_tools(tools)


def chatbot(state: State):
    return {"messages": [llm_with_tools.invoke(state["messages"])]}


graph_builder.add_node("chatbot", chatbot)

tool_node = ToolNode(tools=tools)
graph_builder.add_node("tools", tool_node)

graph_builder.add_conditional_edges(
    "chatbot",
    tools_condition,
)
# Any time a tool is called, we return to the chatbot to decide the next step
graph_builder.add_edge("tools", "chatbot")
graph_builder.set_entry_point("chatbot")
graph = graph_builder.compile()


def stream_graph_updates(user_input: str):
    for event in graph.stream({"messages": [("user", user_input)]}):
        for value in event.values():
            print("Assistant:", value)


stream_graph_updates('Who is Elon Musk?')

Why would this work on the first tutorial step but break on the second?
